# Remove left space from UITableViewCell on setEdit:YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, setediting

I have a `tableView` with some questions that a user can reorder so I have set the property `setEditing` to `YES`

`[questionTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

also I donot want my user to delete any of the rows neither add so I have returned the `UITableViewEdtitingStyle` to  `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;` in its delegate function.

However, the cell has got a lot of space at the left which I need to remove. How can i do that ?
[image]

Comment: just start UITableview frame  X Position to -10.

Comment: I want to set the frame of the cell or the titleLabel not the whole `tableView` @ChandraVaghasiya
i have even tried setting `cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(-10, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height)` but it isnt working

Comment: just try out once as i mention. I hope you will find out what you want.

Comment: I have set the x of the `tableView` to -40 to finish the whole left space but i dont think that its a good idea.. @ChandraVaghasiya